# Setting excel column to auto using Excel::download() method

Tags: excel, laravel

I'm currently generating an excel file (xlsx) by using Excel::download() method but the problem is that some of the column's width is not wide enough to fit its content.

I have did some research and found that I can use the code:-

```
$sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
```

But the problem is that since I'm using Excel::download() to generate the excel file, how do I or where do I declare the code to setAutoSize to true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using something like this (not tested, but should give you an example of what to do) :

```
Excel::download('name', function ($excel) use ($var) {
    $excel->sheet('sheet', function ($sheet) use ($var) {
            $data['var'] = $var; //define your vars here
            $sheet->loadView('view', $var);
            $sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        });
})->export('xls');
```

**Edit:**

If you are using `Maatwebsite\Excel`, this soulution from official package [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html) should do the trick too:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

class InvoicesExport implements ShouldAutoSize
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you !! I will give it a try now :D btw the download method i used is where I actually call "Excel::download(new ExcelHelper($params))", where I pass data into the ExcelHelper's constructor, where should my $params go if I use the method you suggested? Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: Define your parameters above this export function, using the same class: `$params = new ExcelHelper($params)` and then use that variable instead of `$var`